# Google Analytics API returns less (different amount) rows than GA

Tags: r, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm using R to access GA data using RGoogleAnalytics plugin.

I wrote the following query to get the Search Terms from the Site Search from Oct 16 to 22.

```
query <- Init(start.date = "2017-10-16",
                   end.date = "2017-10-22",
                   dimensions = "ga:searchKeyword,ga:searchKeywordRefinement",
                   metrics = "ga:searchUniques,ga:searchSessions,ga:searchExits,ga:searchRefinements",
                   max.results = 99999,
                   sort = "-ga:searchUniques",
                   table.id = "ga:my_view_id")

ga.query2 <- QueryBuilder(query)

ga.data.refined <- GetReportData(ga.query2, token, paginate_query = T)
```

However, this returns 34000 rows, which doesn't match with 45000 row that I see in GA. Note: I did add another dimension to Search Terms.

Interestengly, if I remove `ga:searchKeywordRefinement` dimension from the code and also in GA, the number of rows does match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely caused by sampling in the data.  I can't seem to locate the documentation on how to access this,  but the documentation otherwise makes it clear it is possible:

[RGoogleAnalytics GitHub with Readme](https://github.com/Tatvic/RGoogleAnalytics)

> In cases where queries are sampled, the output also returns the percentage of sessions that were used for the query

So the answer is to access the output that returns the percentage of sessions that were used for the query, and if it less than 100%, then you found your problem.

To solve for sampling... there are some techniques. Review the section in the documentation that talks about splitting your queries into single day, then union all the dates together.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is based on 100% of sessions (in GA). Does the API also return sampled data?

Comment: yes, the API is sampled, and it's sampling is not related to the UI.  Can you confirm what the API response object has to say about whether it's sampled or not?  It should be in your ga.data.refined object

Comment: After calling attributes(ga.data.refined) I don't see the sampling information... I didn't get a response in the log, just that rows have been loaded. I'm assuming it is infact sampled

Comment: Sorry I can't help more!  I'll let you know if I'm able to reproduce on my end